# How do I play a macro, but *slowly* (for debugging a macro)

Tags: neovim, macro

Sometimes I do a repetitive task via a macro, but it ends up too complicated and I make a mistake somewhere. Then when I try to execute the macro, everything happens at once and I can't see where I went wrong, so instead of trying to edit the macro I just attempt to re-record it (with variable success).

Is it possible to set the playback speed of a vim/neovim macro? The idea being that if the macro is executing at 1 command per second (or slower) then I can better tell what went wrong.

Note that I am *not* looking for answers like "just don't use a macro for complex tasks" or "just record the macro bit-by-bit" or "just record multiple simpler macros" or "just look at the relevant register and imagine what those commands would do".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to set the ['writedelay' option](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27writedelay%27). This will delay refreshing the screen by the given number of milliseconds.

So try `:set writedelay=50` and run your macro.

Note, that if you use statusline plugins or similar (which force a lot of redraws), this may get tedious (so you may want to disable this before setting that option).

Comment: That's brilliant! neovim users take note, you'll also need to set `redrawdebug` to `line` in order to see anything: `:set rdb=line wd=100`. Also note that (maybe for syntax highlighting?) neovim seems to redraw the entire screen every now and again, which causes the cursor to *slowly* step through every line top to bottom.

Answer (score 4):

What you could do to achieve something like this is to convert your macro into another one that introduce 1 second delay between the operation using the `1gs` operation or if in insert mode `^o1gs`

e.g.:
If you macro is: `dwihello world^[b` you could convert it into: `dw1gsi^o1gshello world^[1gsb`

Theoretically it should be possible to do that automatically in VimScript but I suspect it will be a very brittle function :-|

Remark: the solution is based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/613312/187713) answer.

Comment: TIL about `gs`, that's pretty neat. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer in case there's another way to do it, but will accept your answer if nothing else comes up.